# Client Side Blazor + Service Worker -> Display Progress in Client

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-5.0

*Config: Hosted (Kestrel) Client Side Blazor (WASM) ASP.NET Core 5 Preview (RC2)*

In my Blazor web application, I'm using a service worker which encodes uploaded video files with [a .NET FFmpeg wrapper/library](https://github.com/rosenbjerg/FFMpegCore).

Someone uploads a video, the service worker checks the directory on the server, when it finds a new upload it starts encoding it. When the task is complete it updates the database. This is already working.

Q: I want to display its progress in the web client, but I don't know where to start. I don't know what I should use to achieve this. Should I do this with SignalR, or can I use gRPC for it? Or is this wrong and should I choose a completely different approach?

I'd rather not use JavaScript. I want to do this in C# / Blazor. And I'd like some guidance on how to do this in C# (sample code or links to code/blogposts).

Comment: You *can* use SignalR or gRPC - both have their good and bad points...You would have to make that choice though - this question will likely get closed by someone for being opinion based ‍♂️

Comment: @MisterMagoo My preference is gRPC, because I'm already using that for my database API's. I'm not using SignalR in my application. I'm using several gRPC examples in my code from the code samples from James Newton-King for example: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/tree/master/examples#blazor. But I'm stuck using this approach from the service worker to the client. They could close this question? I'm sorry, I don't understand 'opinion based' ...

Comment: @MisterMagoo Oh, wait, if I should use gRPC or SignalR is opinion based. I see, okay. But I didn't know if I could use either one for this. So you've actually answered the first part of my question. Thank you.

Comment: Oh a lot of questions get closed when there is no specific "code" question - like this - anyway have you seen this issue https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/928 it alos has links to a sample that JamesNK provided for server to client streaming

Comment: Okay, I understand. I'll check that issue, thank you!

Comment: FYI @MisterMagoo I'm using your Blazored/Video component in this app :)

Comment: If the conversion is happening client-side (via Blazor) you won't need either signalr or grpc since the client already has the progress on their machine

Comment: The conversion (FFmpeg encoding) is happening on the server.